# sm list-disks not found

Tags: android, macos, adb, android-sdcard

I am trying to make my SDcard internal storage on my new Android device.

I have managed to install ADB and Fastboot, although it was not as simple as I hoped and had to install them in usr/local/bin instead of usr/bin.

My next step is to run "sm list-disks" but when I do this returns.

```
adb shell
shell@gtexswifi:/ $ sm list-disks
/system/bin/sh: sm: not found
127|shell@gtexswifi:/ $
```

Not sure what to do next as I think the pathing may be wrong and can't find any posts of a similar issue.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same for a Samsung Galaxy Tab A 7.0. Same issue.

Comment: It's not in busybox either :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try the command `adb shell sm list-disks` (which fixed it for me)